# Log file showing entries in both UTC and Local Time

Tags: centos7, rsync, log-files

I don't know where to start with this one.  I have a Centos 7 server running rsync as a Daemon for backups to copy to, below is a snipit of my rsyncd.log file.  You will see that with every connection from a client the first 2 log entries are in local (EDST) time.  the next 3 entries are in UTC.  I can't figure out out why that is. I would prefer it to be all local time.  I've also included some outputs of my time configuration below.

rsyncd.log:

```
2019/03/16 12:37:00 [29440] name lookup failed for 192.168.10.246: Name or service not known
2019/03/16 12:37:00 [29440] connect from UNKNOWN (192.168.10.246)
2019/03/16 16:37:00 [29440] rsync to Rtemp/ from UNKNOWN (192.168.10.246)
2019/03/16 16:37:00 [29440] receiving file list
2019/03/16 16:46:08 [29440] sent 227465 bytes  received 4197952526 bytes  total size 4871704448

2019/03/16 13:31:00 [1283] name lookup failed for 192.168.10.246: Name or service not known
2019/03/16 13:31:00 [1283] connect from UNKNOWN (192.168.10.246)
2019/03/16 17:31:00 [1283] rsync to Rtemp/ from UNKNOWN (192.168.10.246)
2019/03/16 17:31:00 [1283] receiving file list
2019/03/16 17:31:00 [1283] sent 78 bytes  received 1628 bytes  total size 542134144

2019/03/16 13:33:00 [1286] name lookup failed for 192.168.10.246: Name or service not known
2019/03/16 13:33:00 [1286] connect from UNKNOWN (192.168.10.246)
2019/03/16 17:33:00 [1286] rsync to Rtemp/ from UNKNOWN (192.168.10.246)
2019/03/16 17:33:00 [1286] receiving file list
2019/03/16 17:33:00 [1286] sent 25 bytes  received 1621 bytes  total size 542134144
```

Output of System Date Inquiries:

```
[root@cent7 log]# ls -la /etc | grep localtime
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root     37 Mar  9 00:04 localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Toronto

[root@cent7 log]# hwclock --show
Sat 16 Mar 2019 02:34:12 PM EDT  -0.173067 seconds

[root@cent7 log]# date
Sat Mar 16 14:34:15 EDT 2019
```

.

March 22 2019 Edit:

I have not yet found a solution to this, but confirmed something more:
I started logging each module separately from the global log.  The global log is where the log entries are shown in "set" timezone. Those logs being associated to the connections being made to the daemon.

The module log, where transfer specific logs are recorded (those created by setting the "transfer logging" bool to 1) are the logs done in UTC.

I found this note and bug report on a message board that details my issue exactly and they determined that its because rsync is chroot'ing to a path that cant reach /etc/localtime, and they provide a workaround.  However I am not chroot'd so this shouldn't be an issue should it?
https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2009-March/022772.html
https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4402

Although I'm not chroot'd I'm wondering if SE_linux is possibly preventing the read to /etc/localtime, anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

same issue with ubuntu16.
fixed by `systemctl edit rsync.service`.

```
# systemctl cat rsync.service | tail -3
[Service]
Environment="TZ=:/etc/localtime"
```

- before:

  ```
  # cat /proc/$(pgrep rsync)/environ
  LANG=en_US.UTF-8PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
  ```
- after:

  ```
  # cat /proc/$(pgrep rsync)/environ
  LANG=en_US.UTF-8PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/binTZ=:/etc/localtime
  ```

https://hungryadmin.com/setting-the-tz-variable-for-systemd.html
https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2017-April/017383.html

Comment: This also fixed the problem on Debian 10. Should be the accepted answer, even if it's the only one for now :-) .